# Android: how to test for 64-bit device compatability

Tags: android, 64-bit

I was getting this warning in google play. This release is not compliant with the Google Play 64-bit requirement. The following APKs or App Bundles are available to 64-bit devices, but they only have 32-bit native code

I noticed that my apk had only x86, x86_64, armeabi_v7a folders. So I updated the gradle build script and now I have arm64-v8a folder as well. I see all the .so in armeabi-v7a generated in arm64 too.

How can I validate that this will support 64 bit devices

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create an emulator with 64 bit image, to see that the app works on it.

[image]

Also, in your build variants, you can choose which active abi to use:
[image]

Comment: though the emulator never came up on my Mac. Extremely slow and crashed